# Training loss increases then decreases in LSTM model

Tags: matlab, parameters, lstm, training-data, loss-function

I am training model using LSTM  but it shows increasing loss at the start of training as shown in the attached figure.I believe this is not quite normal in machine learning/deep learning algorithms(the training loss should decrease as epochs increases). Also, my training parameters are given low:

```
options = trainingOptions('adam', ...
    'MaxEpochs',50, ...
    'MiniBatchSize', 1, ...
    'InitialLearnRate', 0.01, ...
    'GradientThreshold', 1, ...
    'plots','training-progress', ...
    'Verbose',false);
```

[image]

Comment: Try decreasing the learning rate to 0.001 or even smaller 0.0001. Also, if using LSTMs prefer RMSprop optimizer if possible.

Comment: Yes i tried to decrease learning rate but it gives me graph like this.https://ibb.co/GnrzyMM

Comment: Wow I have the exact same problem. My loss returns after about 12 iterations. My belief is that the dataset is very consistent at the start, and not so much at the end. Because of this, the model starts at a low loss, than the loss explodes due to the inconsistency at the end. Then, as it learns the pattern, the loss decreases again.